# Visual Studio Code - C Compiler not working (really odd)

Tags: c, visual-studio-code, gcc

I'm compiling using gcc and it says its successfully compiled but its actually doing nothing at all.
Even when I renamed the .c file it said the following:

```
    Terminal will be reused by tasks, press any key to close it.
 Executing task: Initial 

Starting build...
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\gcc.exe -fdiagnostics-color=always -IC:/msys64/Various/freeglut/include/GL -Wall -g -lpthread -c -o Tetris.o Tetris.c

Build finished successfully.<
```

The tasks.json file is:

```
"tasks": [
    {
        "type": "cppbuild",
        "label": "Initial",
        "command": "C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe",
        "args": [
            "-IC:/msys64/Various/freeglut/include/GL",
            "-Wall",
            "-g",
            "-lpthread",
            "-c",
            "-o",
            "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.o",
            "${fileBasenameNoExtension}.c"
        ],
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
        },
        "problemMatcher": [
            "$gcc"
        ],
        "group": {
            "kind": "build",
            "isDefault": true
        },
        "detail": "compiler: C:\\msys64\\mingw64\\bin\\gcc.exe"
    },
```

It also "successfully" links even though the .o file doesn't even exist.  Really weird...

The folder structure in VSCode:

[image]

Comment: How is that compile command generated?  Is your project using a (stale) Makefile?  Have you tried a clean build?

Comment: Its in the tasks.json file in .vscode directory (not make) - if I run the commands from the command line (in MSys64) it compiles correctly - its just in VSC.

Comment: Text should be posted *as text*, not a picture of text.

Comment: sorry.  seemed quicker.  I'll update it...

Comment: Are you sure you are looking into same directory?

Comment: Its the directory VSCode is set to.  (added picture above)

Comment: Just reran it with new filename and it still says it worked but there is no .o file generated.  Even if I run it with the tasks.json file displayed it says (in build window) "tasks.o" and "tasks.c" - still says it was successful even though no such files exists.

Comment: Have you tried searching for `Tetris.o` in file explorer?

Comment: I wondered if it was being generated somewhere else, however when the command said "tasks.o" and "tasks.c" when the tasks.json file was displayed in VSC (it gets the filenames from the currently open file) it still said it was successful even though tasks.c and tasks.o certainly don't exist anywhere.

Comment: Just did search of pc and only Tetris.o file it found was the one I successfully generated (outside VSC in Mingw64 with command line) at lunch time.  I can compile and run it no problem, just not from VSC and I wanted the convenience.